# Prove that $\sqrt{4-x^{2}}$ is continuous on [-2,2] using $\varepsilon \delta$

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $f(x)=\sqrt{4-x^{2}}$ is continuous for all $x\in [-2,2]$.

Proof:

We have to prove that $\underset{x\to x_{0}}{\lim}f(x)=f(x_{0})$ for all $x_0\in [-2,2]$.

$\forall\varepsilon>0\negthickspace\ \exists\delta>0\ |x-x_{0}|<\delta\Rightarrow|\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}|<\varepsilon$

My try:

$|\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-f(x_{0})|\overset{\triangle}{\leq}|\sqrt{4-x^{2}}|+|\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}|=\sqrt{4-x^{2}}+\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}$

$=\frac{(\sqrt{4-x^{2}}+\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}})(\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}})}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}}=\frac{4-x^{2}-4+x_{0}^{2}}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}}=\frac{(x_{0}-x)(x_{0}+x)}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}}<\frac{\delta(x_{0}+x)}{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\sqrt{4-x_{0}^{2}}}$

How do I continue from here or am I even in the right direction?

Comment: Replacing $|M-N| \le |M| +|N|$ will almost certainly fail. We want to show $M$ and $N$ are very close to each other ad $|M|+ |N|$ is not going to be a small number... suppose for instance $x=1.1$ and $x_0=1$.  Then you will have $|\sqrt{2.79} - \sqrt 3| < \sqrt{2.79} + \sqrt 3$.  Can you see why that will be useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need the general inequality
$$\bigl|\sqrt{v}-\sqrt{u}\bigr|\leq\sqrt{|v-u|}\qquad(u\geq0, \ v\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
This inequality (for the proof, see below) also covers the case $u=0$ or $v=0$, where the graph of the function $t\mapsto\sqrt{t}$ has a vertical tangent.

From $(1)$ it follows that for arbitrary $x$, $y\in[-2,2]$ we have
$$\bigl|\sqrt{4-y^2}-\sqrt{4-x^2}\bigr|\leq\sqrt{|y^2-x^2|}\leq\sqrt{|x|+|y|}\sqrt{|y-x|}\leq2\sqrt{|y-x|}\ .\tag{2}$$
Given an $x\in[0,2]$ and an $\epsilon>0$ we should therefore make $2\sqrt{\delta}\leq\epsilon$, or $$\delta:={\epsilon^2\over4}\ .$$
In this case, if $|y-x|<\delta$ and $-2\leq y\leq2$, then, according to $(2)$, one has
$$\bigl|\sqrt{4-y^2}-\sqrt{4-x^2}\bigr|\leq2\sqrt{|y-x|}<2\sqrt{\delta}=\epsilon\ .$$
*Proof* of $(1)$: Assume $0\leq u\leq v$. Then
$$\bigl(\sqrt{v}-\sqrt {u}\bigr)^2=v+u-2\sqrt{v}\sqrt{u}\leq v-u\ ,$$
and taking the square root proves the claim.

Comment: Christian. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

$$|\sqrt{4-x^2}-\sqrt{4-x_0^2}|=\left|\frac{(\sqrt{4-x^2}-\sqrt{4-x_0^2})(\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{4-x_0^2})}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{4-x_0^2}}\right|\\=\left|\frac{4-x^2-4+x_0^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{4-x_0^2}}\right|\\=|x-x_0|\left|\frac{x+x_0}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{4-x_0^2}}\right|$$
The left hand side is $\epsilon$, and the first term in the last line is $\delta$. You can approximate the last term in the last line using $x\approx x_0$.

Comment: This does not cover the two points $x_0\in\{-2,2\}$.

Comment: " You can approximate the last term in the last line using x≈x0. "  Doesn't that beg the question?

Answer (score 0):

Given $x_0\in[-2,2]$ and $\varepsilon>0$, you have to choose your $\delta$. In general, you must do this on a case-by-case basis depending on the function. Here it is not too difficult, because you have a semicircle of radius $2$, which is steepest at its endpoints. This means that if a certain $\delta$ is valid when $x_0$ is one of the endpoints, it will be valid for the whole semicircle.

Now, if the $x$-coordinates of two points on the curve differ by at most $\varepsilon$, the $y$-coordinates differ by at most $\sqrt {2\varepsilon}$ (draw a picture of the semicircle, with $x_0=2$ and $x=2-\varepsilon$, and look for similar right-angled triangles). So you can choose $\delta=\sqrt {2\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your try :
The first inequality $\stackrel{\triangle}{\le}$ goes wrong.
Note that $x_0\in[-2,2]$ is fixed, and so is $f(x_0)$.
You should make $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$, the left hand side of $\stackrel{\triangle}{\le}$, to be smaller than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.
But $|f(x)|+|f(x_0)|$, the right hand side of $\stackrel{\triangle}{\le}$ is not guaranteed to be smaller than $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$.
That is, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(x)|+|f(x_0)|\ge|f(x_0)|>\epsilon.$

My sketch of the proof :
Suppose $x_0=0$ and let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
It is really easy to find $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta$ implies $2-\sqrt{4-x^2}<\epsilon$ ;
Choose $\delta$ so that $2-\sqrt{4-\delta^2}=\epsilon$.
Such $\delta$ must be like $\delta=\sqrt{4-(2-\epsilon)^2}$.

Now suppose $x_0\neq0$. Without loss of generality, let $x_0>0$ and fix $\epsilon>0$.
Since $f''<0$, it can be shown(use Mean Value Theorem, twice) that
$$f(x_0-\delta)-f(x_0)\le f(x_0)-f(x_0+\delta)$$
for small enough $\delta>0$.
Since $f$ is monotonically decreasing, it means that
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le f(x_0)-f(x_0+\delta)$$
for any $|x-x_0|<\delta.$
Thus, choose $\delta>0$ so that $f(x_0)-f(x_0+\delta)=\epsilon.$
Such $\delta$ might have a quite complicated expression like 
$\delta=\sqrt{{x_0}^2-\epsilon+2\epsilon\sqrt{4-{x_0}^2}}-x_0.$

There should be some kind of manipulations in between my proof, so that the proof is indeed rigid.
But I'm pretty sure that my sketch of the proof is precise enough.